# Specify AdditionalReferencePaths from an external .target file

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a bunch of project that requires tweaks to be build in a continuous environement.

I put every tweaks in a separate .target file to reuse this file across all projects.

At the very end of my csproj files, I put (before the closing) `Project` element:

This is working quite well unless I try to include additional reference path.

If I specify using command line the path (`msbuild myproject.csproj  /p:ReferencePath="C:\path\to\dlls"`). The project compile.

My target file is :

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- some tweaks here -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(CompileFor)' == 'SP2013'">
        <SomeProperty>some value</SomeProperty>
        <AdditionalReferencePaths>C:\path\to\dlls</AdditionalReferencePaths>
    </PropertyGroup>      
</Project>
```

But this does not works (dll cannot be resolved).

I also tried :

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <ItemGroup>
            <AdditionalReferencePaths Include="C:\path\to\dlls"/>            
     </ItemGroup> 
</Project>
```

This is not working, because the `ItemGroup` element can't be out of a `Target` element

Lastly, I tried:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">    
    <Target Name="SomeTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">          
        <ItemGroup>
            <AdditionalReferencePaths Include="C:\path\to\dlls"/>              
        </ItemGroup> 
    </Target>    
</Project>
```

This still isn't working. No error, I can see the target is called in the build log, but the DLLs are still not resolved.

**How to fix it?**

To give a bit of context, tweaks I include in the target file allows me to compile the project against different version of DLLs. The code is a plugin of a 3rd party application (SharePoint to name it), and I want to compile for several different versions of the product. Using some conditional, I can target either a folder with one version of the product or another folder for other version of the product.

Comment: You can put Item/Property groups outside of a target, either inside a `.props` file imported higher up in the project file or just directly in the project file near the top/outside of a target. That said, `AdditionalReferencePaths` is not in the list of common MSBuild properties. It appears to have been a part of Team Build only (and the only references to it I can find are from 2005-7). You may have to write your own target that invokes msbuild with your own custom options. Though maybe the properties `AssemblySearchPaths` and `AdditionalLibPaths` may help you

Comment: Note that if you do get this working, consider using Directory.props files so you don't have to do this for every project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of this issue after two fixes.

1. The correct property wasn't `AdditionalReferencePath` but `ReferencePath`
2. I also have to move the `Import` before the first `ItemGroup` of my csproj. I guess this was required to have to properties set before the `Reference` element